# numpy.where() returns empty list, when item satisfy condition

Tags: numpy, h5py

I have an array with values from 0-5, and I want to use numpy.where() to get the indices of where the item equals to 1, but it returns an empty array.

Code:

```
hf = h5py.File(PATH+'/data.h5', 'r')
data = hf['data']                    #dtype int32 [0,1,2,3,4,2,3,1,1,1,4,5,6]
print(data[1] == 1)                  #prints True
indices = np.where(data == 1)[0]     #ERROR here - returns empty array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the dataset to perform tests like this on it.

Using a test file I have hanging around:

```
In [318]: f = h5py.File('data.h5')
In [319]: list(f.keys())
Out[319]: ['dset', 'dset1', 'vset']
In [320]: f['dset']
Out[320]: <HDF5 dataset "dset": shape (3, 5), type "<f8">
```

I can index and test a single item, or slice of the dataset

```
In [321]: f['dset'][1]
Out[321]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
In [322]: f['dset'].shape
Out[322]: (3, 5)
In [323]: f['dset'][...]
Out[323]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

But a boolean test on the dataset does not work:

```
In [324]: f['dset']>0
...
TypeError: unorderable types: Dataset() > int()
```

`==1` works, but compares the dataset objects with 1, and inevitably returns `False`.  That's why `where` gives you an empty result:

```
In [325]: f['dset']==1
Out[325]: False
```

To do the element by element test I have to 'index' the dataset:

```
In [326]: f['dset'][...]>0
Out[326]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I solved it by changing it to: `data = hf['data'] [::]`. Thank you :) I have to wait a couple mins before I can accept your answer.

Comment: I believe you can also call `np.array` on the HDF5 dataset object to create a numpy array.

Comment: I'd recommend `f['dset'].value` over `np.array(f['dset'])`. In any case we need to be aware that there is a difference between the `dataset` and the array in memory.